# convert varchar($22.45) to decimal value(22.45)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column `eng_cost varchar(50)`, values($22.25), ($10.00), () this is not null value its blank value.

When I exporting this data to table2 column eng_cost decimal(15,5) its giving me error.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Output:

```
eng_cost
22.25
10.00
0.00
```

Comment: *Hopefully* you're doing this so that you can correct your datatype in your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to convert to `money`:

```
select convert(money, '$22.25')
```

It handles the currency symbol.  This can then be converted to another number type.

Or, replace the `$`:

```
select convert(float, replace('$22.25', '$', ''))
```

This is less general if you have different currency symbols.